# How to show always the same url?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using Apache.

I have `www.example.com/?p_action=user_profile&post_author=34` and I want to use `www.example.com/niceurl/`

I want that if user enters any of the urls, the `www.example.com/niceurl/` is shown in his browser (of course, `www.example.com/?p_action=user_profile&post_author=34` is actually retrieved from the server).

RewriteRule does not seem to be the solution for this, does it?

Thanks

Comment: anyone? please help...

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try putting,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?p_action=$1&post_author=$2 [L]
```

In your .htaccess file.

IMO RewriteRule should solve your problem.

Comment: With this solution, if I enter "www.example.com/?p_action=user_profile&post_author=34", I will get the proper page, HOWEVER, the url that is displayed in my browser, is still the same. I want it to be replaced and the browser to show "www.example.com/niceurl/"